# Error using dependsOn to call task from another gradle file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am working with a build.gradle file that has multiple ways to specify executions for a task - **setup**. To call a task from another gradle file - runtests.gradle, I created a task - **testTask** and added task dependency using ***dependsOn***, but this implementation does not seem to work and giving out an error like :
***Could not find property 'testTask' on root project 'GradleFile***

My build file looks like this :

> build.gradle

```
task setup(dependsOn: testTask)  <<
 {
    println "In main execution"
}

// new task
task testTask(type: GradleBuild) {
        if (getEnvironmentVariable('RUN_TEST').equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {      
        buildFile = "../Behave/runtests.gradle"
        tasks = ['mainTask']
    }
        else {
        println "Exiting runTests Task"
    }
}

setup.doFirst {
println "In first execution"
}

setup.doLast {
    println "In last execution"
}
```

```
D:\>gradle -q GradleFile/build.gradle setup
```

I am not looking to make much changes to existing tasks, so is there any other workaround I should try?
I have been through many links but could not find anything that suits this scenario. Looking for suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

Gradle is sensitive to the ordering of tasks in the build script if a task instance is given in the `dependsOn`. The task `setup` depends on task (instance) `testTask` which, at the moment the build script is compiled, doesn't exist yet. The most common options to solve the issue are:

- Define task `setup` below `testTask`:

  ```
  task testTask(type: GradleBuild) {
  }

  task setup(dependsOn: testTask) {
  }
  ```
- Use a relative path to the task, i.e. the task's name, in the `dependsOn`

  ```
  task setup(dependsOn: 'testTask') {
  }

  task testTask(type: GradleBuild) {
  }
  ```

Please find more details in Javadoc of [`Task`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#dependencies).

Comment: Worked like charm! Thanks